# Adding aria atributes to dojo widget

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, accessibility, wai-aria

I was doing some accessibility work, and I have currently been adding aria-* attributes as I would any other attribute. Is there a special way of adding aria-* attributes to dojo widgets, or is best practice just to add them like any other attribute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dijit/a11y/resources.html

Using the dijit methods should be much less wordy than manually setting aria- attributes and it handles some browsers specifics for you.